# In beamer, shrunk text override foot line

Tags: latex, beamer

I'm trying to set up my own theme but with my configuration (with a bigger than normal heading) and with shrink option in frame, the text override the footline. I guess it may come from the content height configuration.

[image: Buggy page]

The footline is configured by:

```
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{
\ifnum\thepage>1\relax%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex]{title in head/foot}%
        \hspace*{2mm}
        \usebeamerfont{structure}
        \footnotesize\hspace*{16mm} \Ffootline \hspace{6mm}
        \vspace*{2mm}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
\fi
}
```

If it can help.

Comment: The problem is that beamer calculates the height of head/footline at the start of the document. With your code, it thinks that the footline has no height, because the pagenumber at this point is not >1. To fix this, change the footline only for the title page, not for all pages < 1. I'm thinking of something along the lines of https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=1004#a1198 , but if you want to see some code, please make a compilable(!) [mre]

Comment: Alternatively you could manually force a geometry recalculation after your first page...

Comment: Thank you very much: I think I understand the problem. Maybe a solution would be to have empty footline with a \vspace* (of the right size) ?

Comment: This definitely works. I'm doing the same thing in a beamer theme for my institute.

Comment: Just as an alternative: here an example, how you could force a recalc https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=1397#a1642

Comment: For going further, you were talking about "manually force a geometry recalculation". Any further link about it? I'm definitively interested (I would like to show colleagues that beamer is at least as good as powerpoint) :))

Comment: See the link in my previous comment https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=1397#a1642

Comment: Sorry, forget to expand comments. Very nice. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that beamer calculates the height of head/footline at the start of the document. With your code, it thinks that the footline has no height, because the pagenumber at this point is not >1.

## Solution 1:

To fix this, change the footline only for the title page, not for all pages < 1. You can use a similar approach as in https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=1004#a1198

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\defbeamertemplate{footline}{special footline}{%
  special footline
}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
        \hspace*{2mm}
        \usebeamerfont{structure}
        \footnotesize\hspace*{16mm} Normal footline \hspace{6mm}
        \vspace*{2cm}
}


\makeatletter
\def\ps@navigation@titlepage{%
  \setbeamertemplate{footline}{special footline}
  \@nameuse{ps@navigation}
}
\addtobeamertemplate{title page}{\thispagestyle{navigation@titlepage}}{}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{frame}[shrink]
\frametitle{abc}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

## Solution 2:

Manually force a recalc using the same technique as https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=1397#a1642

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
\ifnum\thepage>1
        \hspace*{2mm}
        \usebeamerfont{structure}
        \footnotesize\hspace*{16mm} Normal footline \hspace{6mm}
        \vspace*{2cm}
\fi 
}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\makeatletter
\beamer@calculateheadfoot
\makeatother

\begin{frame}[shrink]
\frametitle{abc}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

## Solution 3:

Like you proposed yourself, make sure that your head/footline always has the same height, even on the page where it is not visible

---

## Update:

With the [current beamer development version](https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/commit/e5c868041cb51c278420d0b4189693ed569ee3d9) (should be included in beamer v3.70 or newer), beamer now recalculates the head- and footheight at the start of each frame, this making the various workarounds unnecessary.